# How say regex to ignore delimiter which I need delete

Tags: regex

I learned how to work with strings and I have a string like:

```
"one; two\t; "three;2"; four;\t\t"
```

and if this string has "" then I need to ignore delimiter in this ""

I want to get:

```
one two three;2 four
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
I've merged the two expressions approach into the following RegEx that should work in different RegEx compilers that support lookarounds that contian expressions of arbitrary length.

Here is the expression:

```
(?:(?<=\")[^\"]+(?=\"[\t]*;)|\w+)+
```

Testing with the input below:

```
s='"zero,;6"\t\t; one; two\t\t; "three,;2"; four;\t\t; "five;six"\t; "seven";'
```

then running in python (re module's import is not shown):

```
re.findall(r'(?:(?<=\")[^\"]+(?=\"[\t]*;)|\w+)+', s)
```

(*Note*: you could also specify `[\t\v\r\n\f]*` instead of `[\t]*` if your file is expected to contain these additional special characters.)

yields the following list:

```
['zero,;6', 'one', 'two', 'three,;2', 'four', 'five;six', 'seven']
```

**Original**
One way to ignore the delimiter's occurrence inside a double-quoted substring would be by employing lookarounds.

For example to match a double-quoted substring without also including
the quotes in the resulting matched substring, a combination of positive lookahead and lookbehind can be used in the following way:

```regex
(?<=\")([^\"]+)(?=\";)
```

The `(?<=\")` is an assertion for the existence of a preceding double-quote, whereas the `(?=\";)` is an assertion for the existence of a trailing double quote or a semicolon delimiter. The capturing group `([^\"]+)` matches any sequence of characters, except a double-quote to avoid double registration of quotes, inside these quotes. If the above assertions hold then we have a matching substring.

For a normal element, we could match a sequence containing only alphanumeric characters, like this:

```regex
\w+
```

Now combining these two through the use of a non-capturing group
we have:

```regex
(?:(?<=\")([^\"]+)(?=\";)|(\w+))+
```

**Note:** A mandatory step for this approach is to first discard any tab character occurrence. If you are in Python this can be done using the `str`'s method `replace` or using the `re` module's `sub` like this:

```py
re.sub(r'[\t\v\r\n\f]', r'', string)
```

(I also include other special characters, but you can omit them if it is safe for your use case)

Then, you can use either `search` or `findall` from the `re` module, giving the RegEx above.

If you opt for `findall` then you should use the above expression without any group capturing:

```py
re.findall(r'(?:(?<=\")[^\"]+(?=\";)|\w+)+', string)
```

**Example**

For the following input string:

```py
string = '"ty,;6"\t\t; one; two\t\t; "three,;2";  four;\t\t; "fdf;fdfgf"\t; "fdfdf";'
```

Running the substitution step the result is:

```py
> str_clean = re.sub(r'[\t\v\r\n\f]', r'', string)
 '"ty,;6"; one; two; "three,;2";  four;; "fdf;fdfgf"; "fdfdf";'
```

Then, running the final RegEx:

```py
> re.findall(r'(?:(?<=\")[^\"]+(?=\";)|\w+)+', str_clean)
 ['ty,;6', 'one', 'two', 'three,;2', 'four', 'fdf;fdfgf', 'fdfdf']
```